# screen.width not checking for a window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using this script to see if a user that's visiting my site has a screen width smaller than 800. The problem I have is that I also want the alert to be triggered when the user adjusts their screen width to be smaller than 800. How could this be achieved?

At the moment the script only displays the alert when the maximized screen width is lower than 800.

For example, I would like this message triggered when the user has a width of say 1000 but then shrinks their browser width to 720.

```
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.alert("screen smaller than 800");
  }
```

Comment: Listen for the `resize` event in your script

Comment: For future reference, always remember to Google first: a query for `screen.width not checking for a window resize` will already give you all you need. Just FYI.

Comment: Also just FYI if you require this width check because you're amending the UI then using CSS media queries would be a much better solution

Comment: @Pekka웃 I thought we liked making SO become the top answer in google, now it is. Otherwise, we should have closed as a dupe

Comment: @JuanMendes The top 3 other results already are Stack Overflow answers, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
    window.alert("screen smaller than 800");
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: @LewisDay Just remember that using `addEventListener` is the preferred way so you don't overwrite any listeners, also, `screen.width` won't change unless you rotate your monitor :p

Comment: @Juan Mendes True, I agree

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) and you need to get the [window's width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth), not the [screen's width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
   if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
       window.alert("screen smaller than 800");
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dod this with the resize function:

```
var width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(this).width() <= 800) {
    window.alert("screen smaller than 800");
  }   
});
```